# Importing data from Excel/Word into a SharePoint List

Tags: bcs, office-integration, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to import data from an Office Excel or Word file into a list in SharePoint (specifically SharePoint Online)?

I have imported data from SharePoint lists to Word files.

Comment: I have edited your question and changed the wording a little. Please change it if I have missed the point of what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to import Excel data into SharePoint List.
It can be done by creating Import Spreadsheet.
Refer this link...
http://www.bloggix.com/archive/2010/06/15/import-and-export-data-between-excel-2010-and-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 1):

Sure... In list click the **Datasheet View** from the ribbon... and paste your contents from the excel...

Comment: Create the list with the same columns as in the excel sheet...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PowerShell script to import excel saved as csv file.

Here is a [link](http://ravendra.wordpress.com/uploading-csv-excel-data-into-sharepoint-list/) to an example.

With PowerShell you can do some logic too, to make sure it matches your list. E.g. if A equals B then input value C.